# How to use Arrays.asList() to do List functions on arrays

Tags: java, arrays, list

Prompt: Given an array of ints, return true if the array contains a 2 next to a 2 or a 4 next to a 4, but not both.

I have done this with just Arrays and no List methods, but I want to do it this way for practice. Here's what I have, Arrays.asList() is giving me some grief.

```
public boolean either24(int[] nums) 
{
    List list = Arrays.asList(nums);
    boolean twos = list.containsAll(Arrays.asList(2, 2));
    boolean fours  = list.containsAll(Arrays.asList(4, 4));
    return (twos || fours) && !(twos && fours);
}
Expected    Run     
either24({1, 2, 2}) → true  true    OK      
either24({4, 4, 1}) → true  true    OK      
either24({4, 4, 1, 2, 2}) → false   false   OK      
either24({1, 2, 3, 4}) → false  false   OK      
either24({3, 5, 9}) → false false   OK      
either24({1, 2, 3, 4, 4}) → true    false   X       
either24({2, 2, 3, 4}) → true   false   X       
either24({1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4}) → true false   X       
either24({1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4}) → false false   OK      
either24({1, 2}) → false    true    X       
either24({2, 2}) → true true    OK      
either24({4, 4}) → true true    OK      
either24({2}) → false   true    X       
either24({}) → false    false   OK
```

UPDATE: Part of problem was using int instead of Integer. New code:

```
public boolean either24(int[] nums) 
{
    Integer[] nums2 = new Integer[nums.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
        nums2[i] = nums[i];
    List list = Arrays.asList(nums2);
    boolean twos = list.containsAll(Arrays.asList(2, 2));
    boolean fours  = list.containsAll(Arrays.asList(4, 4));
    return (twos || fours) && !(twos && fours);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public boolean either24(int[] nums) {
    return (Arrays.toString(nums).contains("2, 2") ^ Arrays.toString(nums).contains("4, 4"));       
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`containsAll()` does not check if two elements are next to each other. It only checks if the elements exist on the list. You'll need to iterate through the array and check the adjacent elements

```
        int [] nums = new int [] {1,2,3,4,2,3,2,2,1,-4,4,4};
        int len = nums.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < len - 1 ; i++)
        {
            if((nums[i] == nums[i+1]) && (nums[i] == 2 || nums[i] == 4))
            {
                System.out.println("Yes");
            }
        }
```

That snippet above does not give you the answer. You'll still need to handle the `but not both` part of the question, which I'll leave up to you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using the `containsAll` method.  The documentation says:

> Returns true if this list contains all of the elements of the specified collection.

Even though you're passing in 2 twice, it's just checking if the list contains 2.  In other words, it's saying, "Does this list have two? Good.  Does this list have two?  Good"

Answer (score 1):

If it's just about short code, then this would do it too:

```
public boolean either24(int[] nums) {
    String s = Arrays.toString(nums);
    boolean twos = s.contains("2, 2");
    boolean fours = s.contains("4, 4");
    return (twos || fours) && !(twos && fours);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The containsAll checks whether twos/fours is subset of your list. It does not cares about the order.

containsAll is implemented as follows in Java:

```
public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {

// get iterator for collection c
Iterator<?> e = c.iterator();
// loop all elements in collection c
while (e.hasNext())
// if collection A doesn’ have such an element
if(!contains(e.next()))
return false;
return true;

}
```

As you can see it just tells whether the second collection is a subset of the first irrespective of order.
Hence if your list has a sequence say 2, 1, 2, 4 then containsAll would give true for 2's list.

Solution: You can implement your own version of containsAll say containsOrderedAll and call that using above implementation as a reference.

Answer (score -1):

```
  public static boolean is2or4(int[] nums){
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      if(nums[i] == 2){
        return nums[i+1] == 2;
      }else if(nums[i] == 4){
        return nums[i+1] == 4;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

I think the above would be much more efficient.